# UIButton position depending on device and orientation

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, orientation

I have an UIView in which I load some UIButtons programmatically at certain positions (via plist). The positions are based on the screen size of an 9.7" iPad and landscape orientation.
But naturally the buttons don't stay where they belong when you change the orientation or use it on an 12.9" iPad.

What would be the best solution to handle that issue?

**EDIT:**
I did it with tow scale factors, one for orientation and one for the device size. I works quite good.

Comment: Use autolayout instead of hardcoded positions in a plist. This way you can make your interface work for every device, in every orientation, without reading a plist.

Comment: The problem is that it's a kind of catalogue app with about 150 pages and about 400 buttons, so it's not possible to manage that directly in the storyboard